# Connect the local SQL server

Tags: sql, vb6, database-connection, windows-2000

I've been trying to connect SQL Server with VB6. I'm running Windows 2000 on VMWare. I've been unsuccessful in doing so. The error was on the connection string. How can I find the connection string details.

This is the current connection string:

```
.ConnectionString = "user ID=" & DBUser & ";password=" & DBPass & ";" + "Data source=" & strservername & ";" + "Initial Catalog= StudentManagementSystem"
        .Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1"
```

I get the error from err.description

```
Login failed for user 'dbo.'
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of DBUser and DBPass? Have you checked that a SQL login exists in the database matching those values?

Comment: Yes. DBUser = "dbo" and DBPass = ""

Comment: have you opened sql query editor and tried to connect using those credentials?

Comment: also the error says failed for user "dbo.". It's a bit unusual to have a login called dbo - normally that's used for a schema name. Maybe it's getting confused?

Comment: Do you know how to test it with the Query editor?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18026/discussion-between-greg-and-user1122359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing, tried using a trusted connection in the form of

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

and after fixing the servername it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Dbo. Is not a user name its a schema. You need to verify the username.